# How do I find the number of sublists (from every level) of a list in LISP?

Tags: common-lisp

Eg. for list **(A 1 (B 2) (1 C 4) (D 1 (6 F)) ((G 4) 6)) => 6**

Comment: sorry...the answer should be 7 because the list itself is a sublist

Comment: Correct it in your question instead of just commenting.

Comment: It would be great if you put some effort into finding an answer and show what you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick answer would be this:

```
(defun count-sublists (list)
  (if (listp list)
      (1+ (loop for el in list
             sum (count-sublists el)))
      0))
```

Just loop over the elements and recursively count all lists.